# If $Y: G\to H$ is a group homomorphism and $G$ is abelian, prove that $Y(G)$ is also abelian.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

What I got: Suppose $Y$ is a homomorphism and that $G$ is abelian. Then for all $a,b \in G$, $ab=ba$, and thus $Y(ab)=Y(ba)=Y(a)Y(b)=Y(b)Y(a)$.

However, this seems too simple and I was confused on what $Y(G)$ meant (since it wasn't $Y(g)$, I'm not sure if $Y(G)$ is a group or a function.) I need my math.stackexchange buddies to tell me where I probably messed up.

Comment: $Y(G) = \{Y(g) : g\in G\}$ is the image of $G$ under $Y$

Comment: You essentially have it, as the answer points out slightly more formally.  Nice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $h_{1}, h_{2} \in Y(G)$. Then there exist elements $g_{1}, g_{2} \in G$ such that $Y(g_{1}) = h_{1}$ and $Y(g_{2}) = h_{2}$.

So, $h_{1}\cdot h_{2} = Y(g_{1})\cdot Y(g_{2}) = Y(g_{1}\cdot g_{2}) = Y(g_{2}\cdot g_{1}) = Y(g_{2})\cdot Y(g_{1}) = h_{2}\cdot h_{1}$. Hence, $Y(G)$ is Abelian.